# PhantomJs + Watir: Error Message => 'undefined' (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I have been searching this problem for a while on here, but cant seem to find an answer. I am trying automatically fill out a form an submit it with watir using phantomjs as a browser to make it headless. Everything works perfectly with my code when I run it with firefox, but when im using phantomJs, I am getting the following error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': Error Message => 'undefined' (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError)
     caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"160","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:8910","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\".//input[@id='cbxSelectAllPlannedCourses' and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='checkbox']\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d0712620-e3cb-11e4-b75e-e31c63d5c095/element"} (SessionReqHand)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:618:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:586:in `find_element_by'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:88:in `find_first_by_multiple'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:33:in `locate'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:527:in `locate'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:504:in `assert_exists'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/checkbox.rb:29:in `set?'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/checkbox.rb:20:in `set'
        from rabaska.rb:122:in `regrister_cart'
        from rabaska.rb:15:in `main'
        from rabaska.rb:150:in `<main>'
```

The code on line 122 of rabaska.rb is:

```
browser.checkbox(:id => "cbxSelectAllPlannedCourses").set
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add before `browser.checkbox(:id => "cbxSelectAllPlannedCourses").set` - `browser.checkbox(:id => 'cbxSelectAllPlannedCourses').exists?`

Comment: Looks like GhostDriver doesn't support some command. Try updating PhantomJS.

Comment: If there turns out to be some fundamental incompatibility with PhantomJS, you might consider using Ruby's `Headless` gem. That will allow you to continue to use Firefox (or any other browser), but in a headless manner. This seems preferable to me because then you are testing on a browser that humans actually use.

Comment: it seems it is failing when it tries to find the checkbox, based on the stack trace.. yet the error is not a simple could not locate sort of error...   all of which is strange.  Does the same code work with a real browser?